# Can I get Gmail email address by ACS?

Tags: azure, wif, acs

0

HI

Can ACS return Gmail Address today?

Sound like it can be returned before.

But now I use

var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal

And add watch to Thread.CurrentPrincipal, I can only find my name, but I can't find the email address.

Could anybody help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  A user's GMail address should come across as one of the claims.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185929.aspx.

Comment: Correct. Be sure to cast Threat.CurrentPrincipal to an IClaimsPrincipal and then inspect the Claims collection. You should find the email address there.